# Synfony 2.8 one of the two fields must be filled

Tags: forms, symfony, required, checked

I have this form and I want to checked if one of the two fields (`numberPlate` or `expirationDate`) is filled.

This is my `buildForm`:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('type', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'choices_as_values' => true,
            'required' => true,
            'label' => 'Tipo Veicolo',
            'empty_data' => '',
            'empty_value' => '',
            'attr' => array('class'=> 'form-control select2'),
            'choices' => array('Auto' => 'Auto', 'Moto' => 'Moto', 'Camper' => 'Camper' ,'Barca' => 'Barca')
        ))
         ->add('numberPlate', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Targa',
                'required' => false,
                'attr' => array(
                    'class'=> 'form-control',
                    'minlength' => 5,
                    'maxlength' => 7
                    )
            ))
         ->add('expirationDate', DateTimeType::class, array(
             'label' => 'Scadenza',
             'widget' => 'single_text',
             'input'  => 'datetime',
             'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
             'attr' => array('class'=> 'form-control')
         ))
    ;
}
```

Comment: King you need just a validation message error to be shoed if the filed is not filed or you to use event listner on `FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT,`  to acess to the data before. Take a look https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html

Answer (score 2):

You can ensure one of the fields are not empty, by adding a [callback constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/constraints/Callback.html) to your entity.

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContextInterface;

class YourModel
{
   /**
     * @Assert\Callback
     */
    public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
    {
        if (!$this->numberPlate && !$this->expirationDate) {
            $context->buildViolation('Targa or Scadenza is required')
              //optionally display the error at the numberPlate field, omit to display at the top of the form errors
              ->atPath('numberPlate')
              ->addViolation()
              ;
        }
    }
}
```

Then update your Scadenza field as not required.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        //...
         ->add('expirationDate', DateTimeType::class, array(
             'label' => 'Scadenza',
             'required' => false,
             'widget' => 'single_text',
             'input'  => 'datetime',
             'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
             'attr' => array('class'=> 'form-control')
         ))
    ;
}
```

When the form is submitted it will execute the `YourModel::validate` method, and if the `numberPlate` and `expirationDate` are `empty`, it will fail `$form->isValid()`.

Be sure to clear your cache after making the changes, to refresh the annotations.

> **NOTE:** This will apply to any/all forms this entity model is used in,
>   to separate the validation you will need to implement [validation groups](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/form/validation_groups.html)

Comment: He can just use `NotBlank` validation...no need to create another constraint callback

Comment: @Ahmedbhs [`NotBlank`](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/constraints/NotBlank.html) only applies to a single property, and will fail if the property is `empty`. The OP wants to allow one of the two values to be empty. So specifying `NotBlank` on a property alone would cause `isValid` to return `false`.